# Как сделать редирект с URL с двоеточием?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, joomla, mod-rewrite

Добрый день!

На сайте (Joomla 3, Virtuemart 3) есть ссылки вида alcopribor.ru/stati?catid=9&id=136:97-retsept-domashnej-nastojki-chaya-i-vanili-na-samogone

Их требуется редиректнуть на ЧПУ-ссылки вида alcopribor.ru/stati/recepts/97-retsept-domashnej-nastojki-chaya-i-vanili-na-samogone

ЧПУ Артио в Джумле не переваривает исходную ссылку (видимо, из-за get-параметров); пытаюсь через .htaccess наладить, составил вот такое правило:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^catid=9&id=136:97-retsept-domashnej-nastojki-chaya-i-vanili-na-samogone$
RewriteRule ^stati$ http://alcopribor.ru/stati/recepts/97-retsept-domashnej-nastojki-chaya-i-vanili-na-samogone? [R=301,L]
```

На других URL с get-параметрами работало отлично, на этом не работает. Подозреваю что из-за двоеточия в QUERY_STRING. Экранирование двоеточия обратным слэшэм не выручает. Замена ":" на "." ("любой символ") также не даёт результатов.

Как переписать правило редиректа, чтобы оно сработало? Заранее признателен)

Comment: В параметрах URL нельзя использовать двоеточие. Нужно применять percent-encoding

Comment: Кстати, а что будет с вашим редиректом, если параметры в обратном порядке передать?

Comment: Дело было не в двоеточии! Всё начинает работать, если в RewriteRule вместо ^stati$ написать ^(.*)$. Хочу узнать, почему так? Чем ему не мило ^stati$?

Comment: Если параметры передать в обратном порядке - будет страница 404)

Comment: Знак доллара в шаблоне означает конец строки, т.е перенаправляться будет `http://alcopribor.ru/stati`. Когда вы заменили это на `^(.*)$`, под такой шаблон стал подходить любой запрос, который удовлетворяет директивам RewriteCond, стоящим перед этим правилом. У вас же там только одно условие.

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас в файле так же имеется директива RewriteBase

Comment: Т.е. этот $ делает неприменимым правило RewriteRule ^stati$ к запросам вида stati?catid=9... - но ведь get-параметры итак идут в QUERY_STRING и в тело запроса не попадают?

Comment: RewriteBase / написано. Но это как раз и значит, что перенаправляться должны stati, а не http://site.ru/stati

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, самым правильным способом было бы воспользоваться стандартным компонентом перенаправлений в Joomla! Доступ к нему можно получить из меню "Компоненты" -> "Перенаправление". И там добавить записи для каждого URL.

Но если по какой-то причине этот способ не работает, в крайнем случае можно подправить и файл `.htaccess`, добавив для каждого URL правило такого вида:

```
RewriteRule ^stati?catid=[0-9]+&id=136:97-retsept-domashnej-nastojki-chaya-i-vanili-na-samogone$ /stati/recepts/97-retsept-domashnej-nastojki-chaya-i-vanili-na-samogone
```

Если мне не изменяет память, в `.htaccess`, поставляемым с Joomla!, уже присутствует директива `RewriteBase /`, поэтому путь в правиле указан без начального слеша.

Но если таких URL слишком много, можно даже в правиле сделать более общий шаблон. Например,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)?catid=[0-9]+&id=[0-9]+:(.+)$ /$1/recepts/$2
```

И так для каждой категории, но всё же лучше постараться сделать это средствами CMS.

Comment: У нас ЧПУ Артио стоит, который часть ссылок обрабатывает, а часть почему-то нет и их приходится в .htaccess пихать. А вот get-параметры на нашем загадочном хостинге обрабатываются mod_rewrite только через QUERY_STRING, в RewriteRule их не запихнешь)